# how to retrieve data from database in combobox c#

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommand

I wrote this code but I do not know why this line gives error!

```
 String sname = dr.GetString ("name");
```

My code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=logindb;Integrated Security=True");

string query1 = "select * from tbllogin";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1);
SqlDataReader dr;

try
{
    cn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        String sname = dr.GetString("name");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // do smth about exception
}
```

Comment: I am trying to see your error message, but tonight my crystall ball is broken, Could you write it for us?

Comment: Did you try giving the index in GetString() ?

Comment: How do you enter? Index with getstring

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to check this again:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=logindb;Integrated Security=True");
```

`Data Source=.;` This is wrong and it will give you an error.

After that you can use the code below to achieve what you want. The code below also uses `using` statement to dispose the connection.

```
using (
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strCon)) // strCon is the string containing connection string
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from tbllogin", connection);
    connection.Open();
    DataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(int index)); // index of column you want, because this method takes only int
        }
    } 
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: This code gives an error!
What do I need to enter the index?

Comment: If you have a table that contains 2 columns and you want to get 1st column then you write (0) as the index...

Comment: I am sorry for a very late reply. I forgot to check this question and I was just checking my old answer so I checked this and updated my answer as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) says that `SqlDataReader.GetString` method accepts an `int` as a parameter, which is the index of the column.

What you need is this:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    String sname = (string)dr["name"];
    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);
}
```

Here's your code:

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=logindb;Integrated Security=True");
    string query1 = "select * from tbllogin"; SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1); SqlDataReader dr;
    try {
        cn.Open(); dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        { String sname = (string)dr["name"];
        comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "An error occurred!"); }
```

The catch block wasn't written correctly, you missed the `(Exception e)` part.

Comment: thanks :dear friend:but your code:dont work correctly!!!! please give me full code!!!! i am beginner!!!! same above code!!!

Comment: What error (if any) does it give? What does it output? Your expected output?

Comment: Does not give any error!
But what does not show in form
The code I wrote: I am writing again: Maybe the problem is my code

Comment: SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=logindb;Integrated Security=True");
            string query1 = "select * from tbllogin";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1);
            SqlDataReader dr;

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    String sname = (string)dr["name"];
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);
                    
                }

            }

            catch { }

Comment: Please edit your OP and add the code, comments aren't the place to write the code in.

Comment: @user3674314 I've written your code (with a very minor fix) in my post, see above.

Comment: That's because your connection string isn't valid.

Comment: My connection is correct but I do not know why the error occurs!
You have to test my code?
I got this code from the internet!!

Comment: Be complete about your questions, what error are you getting and what line is being reported?

Comment: Please look at the following picture: Image Link: This error occurs only

Comment: As i said before, your connection string is not valid. The `Data Source` parameter is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

(Amazingly) `GetString` only take an index as parameter.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public override string GetString(int i)
```

With no other signatures :-(

However you could write:

```
String sname = dr.Item["name"].ToString();
```